# Github Actions Kubernetes-Hosted Runner - Token Best Practices

Tags: github, kubernetes, github-actions, access-token

I'm setting up a self-hosted github runner on a k8s cluster. The runner deployment requires that I supply it a token so that it can link to the proper repository/github account.

There are a lot of examples that I've seen that use a Personal Access Token as a secret resource. It seems like bad practice to use a single user's PAT for what should be a service account token. I am wondering if there are recommended way to use a repository or organization-level token stored as a secret.

Possibly the GITHUB_TOKEN, but this seems too transient as it appears to expire following the completion of a workflow.

Curious about best practices in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a registration token for an organization following this [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-registration-token-for-an-organization).

From this [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#self-hosted-runner-security) Github recommends that you only use self-hosted runners with private repositories. This is because forks of your public repository can potentially run dangerous code on your self-hosted runner machine by creating a pull request that executes the code in a workflow.
Do not store secrets in the host runner When a GitHub Action uses the self-hosted runner, it clones the code in a workdir _work.We must ensure that no secrets (application, system, ..) are accessible in this folder.

For more information follow this [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners?apiVersion=2022-11-28#example-using-registration-token).